# Reading and store ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following in my controller:

```
            ViewBag.ProjectID = ID;
```

How can retrive the projectID in the following in javascript?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "@Url.Action("Delete")",
        data:
        {
            ***projectID : $("#ProjectID").val()*** 

        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data: { 'projectID' : '@ViewBag.ProjectID' }
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Following should work

```
"projectID" : "@ViewBag.ProjectID"
```